# Azure Function timer trigger not always firing according to schedule

Tags: timer, azure-functions

I need some help, because I don't know if I did something wrong or this is simply a bug. I have written a simple azure function using node.js that uses a timer trigger on a consumption plan and should trigger by its TCRON expression every 5 minute, but when I take a look into the application insights "request" data I can see that it does in fact not trigger every 5 minutes. It leaves out some intervals.

Here are some facts:

- My function does not require more than 5 minutes to execute it takes about 2 seconds.
- I also have app insight data sampling disabled in the configuration.
- No I did not change my config or deploy during that intervals left out.
- Yes I am aware that it does not exactly trigger ever 5 minutes sharp. But it should be somewhat near to that.

Requests in App Insight Logs entry timestamps that show that intervals are missing:

3/16/2021, 9:34:59.996 AM
3/16/2021, 9:29:59.996 AM
3/16/2021, 9:20:00.002 AM
3/16/2021, 9:05:00.018 AM
3/16/2021, 8:50:00.006 AM
3/16/2021, 8:35:00.000 AM
3/16/2021, 8:24:59.993 AM

function.json of the azure function in question contain the CRON expression

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

host.json of the app

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```